# Google Drive Apps by Content Type

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api

Google Drive lets the user select an app for viewing different content types. Does it already or will it ever suggest drive apps which can handle the specific content type the user is trying to view? When?

Ex. If I try to open up an MP3 from Google Drive with the option Open With->Get More I see all Google Drive apps. But I only want to see apps supporting the content type for MP3.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive already only shows the applications that support a given file type when opening the Open With contextual menu:

https://developers.google.com/drive/apps-overview#opening_and_creating_files_from_the_drive_ui

Also, Google Drive promotes existing apps that can open a given file type when the user doesn't have them installed:

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/08/help-users-find-your-app-with-mime-type.html